# Lambda capture and parameter with same name - who shadows the other? (clang vs gcc)

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, language-lawyer, shadowing

```
auto foo = "You're using g++!";
auto compiler_detector = [foo](auto foo) { std::puts(foo); };
compiler_detector("You're using clang++!");
```

- **clang++ 3.6.0** and newer print out *"You're using clang++!"* and warn about the **capture** `foo` being unused.
- **g++ 4.9.0** and newer print out *"You're using g++!"* and warn about the **parameter** `foo` being unused.

What compiler is more accurately following the C++ Standard here?

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/FFngRM4CwRdtcCBl)

Comment: So basically, g++ *sort-of* translate `std::puts(foo);` into `std::puts(this->foo);` in the generated class (equivalently speaking), whereas clang doesn't do that.

Comment: Pasting the code from wandbox to [here](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) (they seem to have forgotten the share button) makes it seem like VS2015 (?) agrees with clang saying *warning C4458: declaration of 'foo' hides class member*.

Comment: The lambda has a type with a template function call operator, thus the logic would make me say that the parameter should shadow the captured variable as if in `struct Lambda { template<typename T> void operator()(T foo) const { /* ... */ } private: decltype(outer_foo) foo{outer_foo}; }`.

Comment: @nwp VS is wrong, data members of the lambda are unnamed and thus cannot be shadowed. The standard says "access to a captured entity is transformed to access to the corresponding data member", which leaves us at the square one.

Comment: @n.m. Well, those unnamed data members are still accessed by using an identifier. Therefore, the parameter name should at least (let me say) _hide that identifier_. Am I wrong?

Comment: @skypjack this appears to be correct. Ostensibly the lambda body doesn't access the capture, it accesses the original captured entity, which should be shadowed normally according to scope rules.

Comment: @n.m. Do you think it's worth it to make an answer of my comments?

Comment: @skypjack why not, go ahead

Comment: I would hope the clang version is correct - it would be breaking new ground if something outside of a function shadows the function parameter, instead of the other way around!

Comment: @M.M Actually, put aside the standard, common sense is another good reason to say that GCC is wrong in this case. You're right. ;-)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Update: as promised by the Core chair in the bottom quote, the code is [now ill-formed](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#capture-5):

> If an *identifier* in a *simple-capture* appears as the *declarator-id* of a parameter of the *lambda-declarator*'s *parameter-declaration-clause*, the program is ill-formed.

---

There were a few issues concerning name lookup in lambdas a while ago. They were resolved by [N2927](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2927.pdf):

> The new wording no longer relies on lookup to remap uses of captured entities. **It more clearly
>   denies the interpretations that a lambda's *compound-statement* is processed in two passes or that any names in that *compound-statement* might resolve to a member of the closure type.**

Lookup is always done in the context of the *lambda-expression*, never "after" the transformation to a closure type's member function body. See [[expr.prim.lambda]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#8):

> The *lambda-expression*'s *compound-statement* yields the *function-body* ([dcl.fct.def]) of the function call operator, but for purposes of name lookup, […], the *compound-statement* is considered in the context of the *lambda-expression*. [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> struct S1 {
>   int x, y;
>   int operator()(int);
>   void f() {
>     [=]()->int {
>       return operator()(this->x+y);  // equivalent to: S1::operator()(this->x+(*this).y)
>                                      // and this has type S1*
>     }; 
>   }
> };
> ```
>
> —*end example* ]

<sub>(The example also makes clear that lookup does not somehow consider the generated capture member of the closure type.)</sub>

The name `foo` is not (re)declared in the capture; it is declared in the block enclosing the lambda expression. The parameter `foo` is declared in a block that is nested in that outer block (see [[basic.scope.block]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.block#2), which also explicitly mentions lambda parameters). The order of lookup is clearly [from inner to outer blocks](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.unqual#6). Hence the parameter should be selected, that is, Clang is right.

If you were to make the capture an init-capture, i.e. `foo = ""` instead of `foo`, the answer would not be clear. This is because the capture now actually [induces a declaration](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#12) whose "block" is not given. I messaged the core chair on this, who replied

> This is issue 2211 (a new issues list will appear on the open-std.org site shortly, unfortunately with just placeholders for a number of issues, of which this is one; I'm working hard to fill in those gaps before the Kona meeting at the end of the month). CWG discussed this during our January teleconference, and **the direction is to make the program ill-formed if a capture name is also a parameter name.**

Comment: Nothing for me to rip apart here :) A *simple-capture* declares nothing, so the correct result of the name lookup is fairly obvious (BTW, GCC gets it right if you use a *capture-default* instead of explicit capture). *init-capture*s are somewhat trickier.

Comment: @T.C. I agree. I filed a core issue, but apparently this has been discussed already, see the edited answer.

Answer (score 6):

I'm trying to pack together a few comments to the question to give you a meaningful answer.
First of all, note that:

- Non-static data members are declared for the lambda for each copy-captured variable
- In the specific case, the lambda has a closure type which has a public inline template function call operator accepting a parameter named `foo`

Therefore the logic would make me say at a first glance that the parameter should shadow the captured variable as if in:

```
struct Lambda {
    template<typename T> void operator()(T foo) const { /* ... */ }
    private: decltype(outer_foo) foo{outer_foo};
};
```

Anyway, @n.m. correctly noted that the non-static data members declared for copy-captured variables are actually unnamed. That being said, the unnamed data member is still accessed by means of an identifier (that is `foo`). Therefore, the parameter name of the function call operator should still (let me say) *shadow that identifier*.
As correctly pointed out by @n.m. in the comments to the question:

> the original captured entity [...] should be shadowed normally according to scope rules

Because of that, I'd say that clang is right.

Comment: As explained above, lookup in this context is never performed as if we were in the transformed closure type.

Comment: @Columbo I'm adding a line that I missed even if it was clear from the reasoning, that is that clang is right. The funny part is that I found [expr.prim.lambda]/8 while trying to give an answer, but I've not been able to use it properly as you did. That's why every time it's a pleasure to read your answers. ;-)