# My program keeps looping and never get's to "return 0;". Is it the compiler that's bad or the code?

Tags: c++, loops, infinite-loop, logical-operators

My program keeps looping and never get's to "return 0;". Is it the compiler that's bad or the code?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string nameInput = "";
    string Input = "Yes";
    cout << "Welcome to the purple casino!" << endl << "What's your name?" << endl;
    while(Input =="Yes" || "yes"){
        getline(cin, nameInput);
        cout << nameInput << ", what a nice name!" << endl << "Do you want to change it?" << endl;
        getline(cin, Input);
        if(Input =="Yes" || "yes"){
            cout << "To what?" << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "Let's begin!";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rule of thumb: it's you, not the compiler!

Comment: Aside from the yucky indentation, this is well-asked.

Comment: at least in 99.99% of the cases, see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42088015/lambda-capture-and-parameter-with-same-name-who-shadows-the-other-clang-vs-g for a counterexample.

Comment: `if(Input =="Yes" || "yes")` -- You'll discover that C++ doesn't know shorthand English-speak.  We may say "if x equals this or that", but that is not how you "say" this in C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Although some programming languages do.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes, but I usually see this mistake being made because the new coder translates their English to a C++ conditional statement.

Comment: In Cobol you can actually write `IF Input IS EQUAL TO 'YES' OR 'yes'` and that has worked since 1960. Who says that programming language design improves over time?

Comment: @BoPersson -- Yes that's true about COBOL.  However COBOL was written for the English speaker, so the shortcut language sort of fits in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `Input == "Yes" || "yes"` is evaluated, due to *operator precedence*, as

`(Input == "Yes") || "yes"`

which is always `true`. This is because the `const char[4]` literal `"yes"` *decays* to a `const char*` type, with a non-zero pointer value.

You need `Input == "Yes" || Input == "yes"`

Answer (score 5):

> My program keeps looping and never get's to “return 0;”. Is it the compiler that's bad or the code?

The code, as (almost) always.

`Input =="Yes" || "yes"` will always evaluate to `true`, no matter what `Input`'s value really is, since it boils down to saying:

- `true` if: `Input` equal to "Yes" OR "yes".
- `false` if otherwise.

A string literal evaluates to `true`, thus the second operand of the logical or will be `true`, causing the whole logical expression to evaluates to `true`, always!

As a result your while loop's condition is always true, resulting in an infinite loop!

So change this:

```
while(Input =="Yes" || "yes")
```

to this:

```
while(Input =="Yes" || Input == "yes")
```

PS: Change the condition of the if statement similarly, since it's the same exact condition.

Answer (score 2):

Your `while` statement's condition is wrong:

```
while (Input == "Yes" || "yes")
```

as `"yes"` operand always evaluates to `true` causing the entire condition to be `true`. Try this instead:

```
while (Input == "Yes" || Input == "yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a silly mistake in your code. Please see the below edited code -

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
string nameInput = "";
string Input = "Yes";
cout << "Welcome to the purple casino!" << endl << "What's your name?" << 
endl;
while(Input =="Yes" || Input == "yes"){ // Error was here
getline(cin, nameInput);
cout << nameInput << ", what a nice name!" << endl << "Do you want to             
change it?" << endl;
getline(cin, Input);
if(Input =="Yes" || "yes"){
cout << "To what?" << endl;
}
}
<< "Let's begin!";
return 0;
}
```

Try modifying `while(Input =="Yes" || "yes"){` to `while(Input =="Yes" || Input == "yes"){`

I think the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Hi before return try : 
`cout << "Let's begin!";`
And change in While and if your condition to: 
`(Input =="Yes" || Input=="yes")`

Answer (score 0):

In a more general way, if you have a loop from which your program never returns, it means that the condition you passed always evaluates to `true`.
In your case indeed, an as others already answers, the condition

```
while (Input == "Yes" || "yes")
```

always evaluate to true because of the second part.
What you really want is to check if Input is "Yes" OR Input is "yes", which in C++ should be written :

```
while (Input == "Yes" || Input == "yes").
```

Hope, this more general answer will help.