# how to pass local variable and argument of same name (using this keyword )inside lambda functions in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, functional-programming, inline-functions

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
int main(){
    int a = 10; 
    std::function<int(int)> functionPointer = [a](int a)-> int{ return a + a + 100 ; };
    int returnValue = functionPointer(50);
    std::cout<<returnValue<<endl;
}
```

I was expecting 10+50+100 = 160 but the output is 10+10+100 = 120. Are there any changes I can make to get 160, whilst keeping the variable names as they are?

Comment: Why don't you rename the function argument?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lambda capture and parameter with same name - who shadows the other? (clang vs gcc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42088015/lambda-capture-and-parameter-with-same-name-who-shadows-the-other-clang-vs-g)

Comment: what about ***[a](int x)-> int{ return a + x + 100 ; };***

Comment: Yes, but... I just want to know ....it is possible or not with same name

Comment: No. it's not possible.

Comment: Formally speaking the program is *ill-formed*. That means a compiler may well fail to compile the code, or if it doesn't, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually there is a way to solve this problem without changing the variable or parameter name, by aliasing the capture:

```
std::function<int(int)> functionPointer = [b=a](int a)-> int{ return a + b + 100 ; };
```

As [explained here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#lambda-captures), since C++14 lambda capture is generalized, which includes renaming variables of the lambda object. While a capture `[a]` would copy local variable `a` from outer scope into a lambda object variable `a`, we can also name that lambda object variable with the syntax `[b=a]`, so the lambda's copy is known as `b`. We can also define lambda object variables with expressions, e.g. `[a=5*a]` or `[b=5*a]`, which is sometimes a neat way of e.g. passing members of a struct or results of accessor methods to a lambda.

It allows to do things previously not possible, namely passing a `unique_ptr` to the lambda object (i.e. transferring ownership!) with `std::move()`.

Comment: This is a C++14 feature described here: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#lambda-captures

Comment: Nice – in the sense of the question, but is harder to read than just renaming the parameter, which I consider more recommendable (@RohitBakoliya)...

Comment: Yes, I consider this an academic question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no way to do exactly what you would like to as the compiler cannot have one variable `a` with two different values.

Comment: It cannot have one variable with two different values, but it can have more than one variable with the same name, quite a number of examples exist, and actually, question author asks for another one (which, as presented, is ill-formed, though).